# Is there an install DVD with multiple interface choices?

Tags: dvd, interface

I would like to be able to burn a single DVD containing multiple interfaces. The Ubuntu live CD image is 700MB so there should be loads of room. Maybe the languages packages could be put on it as well?

I think Mandriva could do this. You basically chose which interface you wanted when you installed.

Is there any Ubuntu Live DVD with that?

Answer (score 1):

No, while many distributions come with this feature, Ubuntu lacks it. There are plenty of derivatives such as Kubuntu and Lubuntu each with its own desktop so you should be able to find your preferred desktop environment with one of them. If you want Gnome or multiple desktops the only way way to get them is to find their meta packages in Synaptic and install them from there. Bear in mind though, this means you will end up with all applications from both environments.
Information on installing new desktop environments can be found [at Psychocats](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/) in the "Playing Around" section.

Comment: I feared you might say that. I don't really like installing lots of interfaces side by side. I'm sort of in a transitional phase regarding interfaces at the moment. I'm not sure what I want, I just don't want Unity.

Comment: I'm in the same position. Unfortunately I have been forced to stick with Windows 7 until Unity or Gnome 3 gets a bit more polish. XFCE is a pretty good Gnome 2 replacement, but the apps aren't really up to scratch, same with LXDE. Of course, that can be solved with a little bit of time on Synaptic so they are really as solid as a desktop gets right now in Linux.